# Automatically set the value of a column from a function or query

Tags: mysql

I have a MariaDB database and I have table `userInfo` which has a column of `ipAddress` and `country`. I want to have another column named `country` and automatically get the country from the `ipAddress` and insert it in the `country` column. I already imported GeoIPLite2 and already have a SQL Query but I dont know how to use make mariadb do it instead of doing it on my code.

```
SELECT a.country_name
FROM geoipcountries a, geoipblocks b
WHERE INET_ATON('1.2.3.4') BETWEEN network_start_integer AND network_last_integer
AND b.geoname_id = a.geoname_id
```

This query give me the country name.
I want the MySQL to set the value of `country` column in `userInfo` table from the output of the query above.

I already wrote this function as well:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getIpCountry(ip varchar(15)) RETURNS varchar(64)
BEGIN
declare result varchar(64);
select SQL_CACHE a.country_name into result FROM geoipcountries a, geoipblocks b WHERE INET_ATON(ip) BETWEEN network_start_integer AND network_last_integer AND b.geoname_id = a.geoname_id;
if (result is null) or (result = '') then
set result := 'unknown';
end if; 
return result;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: use `trigger` for that and set `NEW.country = getIpCountry(NEW.ipAddress)`

Comment: @JitendraYadav I dont know how to create that trigger. Can you please tell? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you want to change all county names in one goal

Do a

```
UPDATE userInfo SET `country`= getIpCountry(`ipAddress `);
```

But today we use join and not comma separated tables

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getIpCountry(ip varchar(15)) RETURNS varchar(64)
BEGIN
declare result varchar(64);
SELECT 
    a.country_name
INTO result 
FROM
    geoipcountries a
        INNER JOIN
    geoipblocks b ON b.geoname_id = a.geoname_id
WHERE
    INET_ATON(ip) BETWEEN network_start_integer AND network_last_integer;
if (result is null) or (result = '') then
set result := 'unknown';
end if; 
return result;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

To d that automatically you need a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER before_userInfo_insert
BEFORE INSERT
ON userInfo  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.`country`= getIpCountry(NEW.`ipAddress `);

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

and a `BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER`

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_userInfo_update
BEFORE UPDATE
ON userInfo  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.`country`= getIpCountry(NEW.`ipAddress `);

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you table is `userInfo` and you want your `country` column to auto populate based on `ipAddress`. Use [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `userinfo_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `userInfo` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.country = getIpCountry(NEW.ipAddress);
END $$
```

**Note**: If `ipAddress` can be null, so make sure you handle that in your function `getIpCountry` function.

Same you can on on `update` event too.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `userinfo_before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `userInfo` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.country = getIpCountry(NEW.ipAddress);
END $$
```

Now just skip `country` column from both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` query and make sure to include `ipAddress`. It would be like as follow

```
INSERT INTO userInfo(user_id, ipAddress) VALUES (1, '172.16.6.20');

UPDATE userInfo SET ipAddress = '172.16.6.20' WHERE user_id = 1;
```